# chart zoom bar growing automatically - AmChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

**AmChart column chart**

I been facing some performance issues with the scroll and zoom (in/out) with huge data. For that I found a [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359941/bar-chart-slow-zoom-in-out-amcharts) and its working with no lag.

But after setting `updateOnReleaseOnly = true` (as per the above solution) when I scroll the chart, scrollbar is growing up automatically

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulwahabplus/6eqe272y/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AmChart team has fixed it in version 3.21.6